# Does using Constructor Result in a JPA or Hibernate query affect performance?

Tags: java, mysql, performance, hibernate, jpa

I have the following query in my Java DAO class:

```
Query query = session.createQuery(
    "select new Question(q.qid, q.qtype) from Question q where q.qlang=:lang "
);
```

1. Does using the new constructor in a hibernate query affect performance? In what way is it affected?
2. Be it the above java code or the SQL query it gets converted into or, the assembly of the SQL result into a `Question` object, does it increase or decrease the overall performance of the application?

Comment: What is Reference Type? Is it the Constructor Result? What is "new object type"?

Comment: @VladMihalcea - Sorry for the confusion. I have updated it.

Comment: And I have answered it.

Comment: @VladMihalcea Thanks a ton.

Comment: @VladMihalcea Sure, I will go through that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about Constructor Result, then you should ask yourself a different question before worrying about performance.

> Is the JDBC `ResultSet` suitable for my data access layer, service
>   layer, and the UI?

For most applications, the answer is **No**. The tabular JDBC `ResultSet` is not a good fit for an application developed in an OOP language because you need graphs of objects, even when pushing the results to the clients (e.g. JSON).

For this purpose, you either need DTOs or entities.

- [DTOs are suitable for read-only projections](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) and performance is mostly dictated by how efficient the SQL query is and how much data you fetch. The [lack of pagination in your query](https://vladmihalcea.com/whats-new-in-jpa-2-2-stream-the-result-of-a-query-execution/) is much more of a problem than the fact that you are projecting a DTO result set.
- entities for writing data because you can benefit from [batching](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-do-batch-processing-with-jpa-and-hibernate/), [lost update prevention](https://vladmihalcea.com/preventing-lost-updates-in-long-conversations/), automatic [dirty checking](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-anatomy-of-hibernate-dirty-checking/).